# Convert an old VB.Net web project to a new responsive one

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, responsive-design

I am trying to convert an old VB.Net web project to a new responsive one, but got stuck translating the codebehind code to MVC because it is too complex and large, and I do not have time to create a new database. What frameworks or solutions do you recommend? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: This isn't even close to a question for this site.  It is 100% up to you to do your research and decide what tools are best for your requirements.  And if your looking to migrate existing projects to new tech stacks, it is better to just do it rather than try and short cut it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would the database have ANY reflection on the web site, and if that web site is to be responsive or not?

In fact, when making a transition from one software platform to another, if the database is already SQL server, then ZERO changes to that database are required. In fact it is the one thing that you can recover, re-use and not change at all. It is the MOST re-useable part of the application, and can be 100% re-used without any changes. So I must be failing one of the most huge issues in regards to suggest, hint, or blame the database as being ANY kind of factor here in re-writing software.

On the other hand, why re-write?

For at least 10 years, the default for asp.net webforms sites includes bootstrap, and thus all web pages can and should be 100% "responsive" based on that fact.

I mean, lets say we dropped in a gridView.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels  Order by HotelName ", conn)

            conn.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And say this markup:

```
       <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="Row Click"
                            OnClick="cmdRow_Click"
                            />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        </div>
```

Ok, so we have this:
[image]

So, the grid does not full out the whole page.

Lets make it responsive.

Just add CssCass = "table table-hover" to the GV

Like this:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      CssClass="table table-hover"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
```

And say same for the button CssClass="btn"

Presto!! - the grid is now responsive - fills out the whole page like this:

presto, we now get this:

[image]

And we even get hover effects, and you even get total responsive re-sizing of that grid - all the way down to even a good mobile rendering.

So, now the grid is a 100% full blown bootstrap "responsive" grid. And it took me LESS time to make this change then to write this post!!!

You can go off and built a grid in PHP, or MVC - you get much the SAME results - a nice bootstrap "responsive" grid.

So, the database is the last, and least of your worries.

I mean, because you out of the blue decide to convert to MVC? That does ZERO ZERO ZERO for gaining you a responsive web site - it does nothing for you.

So, I don't see why not a simple introduction of boot strap classes to the existing web pages would not suffice here? You not going to by some act of magic get a responsive web site because you now adopting MVC, you ONLY get that responsive web site by introduction of a responsive framework (say like bootstrap).

As I stated, even 10+ year old asp.net sites based on webforms in 99% of cases ALREADY have the bootstrap framework included - and in fact included by default.

But regardless, 100% ignoring the above? The database effects this result and outcome ZERO, and does not effect how much, or how little, or even ONE BIT that the resulting web site will be a responsive result.

I mean, sure, toss in jQuery.UI for say some nice dialogs etc, and you can even use bootstrap dialogs with jQuery - and again, all this 100% works fine in that webforms application.

I mean to blow all that money and time converting to MVC? That suggests you sat down, and had a bunch of new work and new features, and the developer team was a WELL oiled and versed group of developers that are REALLY good at MVC, since as a general rule, MVC takes more effort, more time, and more work to produce the same effects as webform. This is especially the case, since with datalist, gridview, and especially listview?

Why?

In MVC, you own your own. And when you google some grid solution, you get 50 different approaches, since there not one defined say Listview or control you have in MVC. And better yet, I find VAST MORE consistency in wewbforms applications, since if you used a Gridview, then the SAME event model applies to listview, datalist, repeater and more controls.

With MVC, you have to build up and cook up how you going to put up a grid, since you don't have a built in choice of such controls.

The other advantages of MVC, is that it allows you to scale out to more users, but in 99% of cases, increased performance was not really realized if the webforms code was well done. Poor code and poor designs has ZERO to do with web forms vs say that of MVC. it all comes down to good designs. but, since with MVC you MUCH more on your own to approach just about anything - including things say like listview etc., the you often find a MUCH greater mess and lack of consistency in the MVC application, since no one defined or established means to display say a grid as listview does not exist.

In fact, since you have to go out to web land and find that 3rd party control? Well, then the whole reason for using MVC over say PHP or some other systems quite much goes out the window. (and thus  the adoption rate of new asp.net developers has really suffered greatly).

Regardless of the above, there is nothing at all in regards to the choice or fact of a database system having ANY effect on you deciding to build your web site around a responsive framework like bootstrap, and in fact as I stated, you can and should just introduce bootstrap into those existing webforms anyway - the result will not be any more or less "responsive" then having adopted MVC.